# Why do I have to make an AJAX request twice to dispaly primefaces <p:dataTable when using <p:columns in it?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow

I'm using a primefaces  with  to display a dynamic set of columns, like this :

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{queryResults}" var="row" style="margin-top:15px;">
         <p:columns value="#{row.cells}" var="cell" headerText="#{cell.field.label}" rendered="#{not cell.field.hidden}">
               <h:outputText value="#{cell.value}" />
          </p:columns>
    </p:dataTable>
```

My environment is Majorra 2.0.3, PF 3.5, Spring Webflow 2.3 on tomcat 7

When i hit my command button an expect result I get an partial response but the table has no cells :

```
    <div id="alertForm:j_idt58" class="ui-datatable ui-widget" style="margin-top:15px;">
          <table role="grid"><thead><tr role="row"></tr></thead><tfoot></tfoot>
          <tbody id="alertForm:j_idt58_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content">
              <tr data-ri="0" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"></tr>
              <tr data-ri="1" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"></tr>
              <tr data-ri="2" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-even" role="row"></tr>
              <tr data-ri="3" class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-odd" role="row"></tr>
          </tbody></table></div>
```

even though the java code is called, rows are returned as expected. I hit the button a second time, same java code is called, but partial response conatins the datatable and its cells, hence it is displayed correctly...

What do I miss ?

Note : with combination of datatable + several column, everything work just fine...

Comment: It might be related to the `rendered="#{not cell.field.hidden}` condition and the scope of your backing bean (what is the scope of your backing bean?). The timing may not be right between both. Have you tried the same code without the render condition?

Comment: yes I have tried, but not working... I have tried with a non ajax request it does not work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was : the following : (read the manual) p:columns is only used to display headers and create index variable (columnIndexVar) that allows you to access your data in an "old fashion" indexed way.

The manuel says :

> *Dynamic Columns
>   Dynamic columns is handy in case you can’t know how many columns to render. Columns component is used to define the columns programmatically. It requires a collection as the value, two iterator variables called var and columnIndexVar.*

```
<p:dataTable var="cars" value="#{tableBean.dynamicCars}" id="carsTable">
    <p:columns value="#{tableBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{column}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{cars[colIndex].model}" /> <br />
        <h:outputText value="#{cars[colIndex].year}" /> <br />
        <h:outputText value="#{cars[colIndex].color}"/>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try having the `<p:datatable>` in a separate `<h:form>` that solved the issue for me.